# adding two variables in href to be sent

Tags: php

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I want to include two variables in an `href`

the href is not in a form

```
<div class="button"> 
  <a href="<?php fetchdir($ipages) ?>product.php?Name=<?php echo$name>">View</a> 
</div>
```

int he page I am sending it to i have a Get method

```
if (isset($_GET['Name']) && isset($_GET['pid'])) {
$id2 = $_GET['Name']; 
$id = $_GET['pid'];
```

**Summary**
I want to include $id in the `a href` so i will be able to get both name and id in the page `product.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good way to build a property encoded is to use the http_build_query function, this will ensure that the data sent in the request is properly encoded.

```
<?php
    $qstr = http_build_query(array("Name"=>$row["Name"], "id"=>$row["pid"]));
?>
<a href="<?php fetchdir($ipages) ?>product.php?<?= $qstr ?>">
```

This of course can also be done inline

```
<a href="<?php fetchdir($ipages) ?>product.php?<?= http_build_query(array("Name"=>$row["Namw"], "id"=>$row["pid"])) ?>">
```

Comment: one thing for `$name = $row["Namw"];` and `$id= $row["pid"];`

Comment: @SarahJames updated with date from the example, also balanced the parens.

Answer (score 3):

You can append as many URL parameters as you like using `&`:

```
<a href="<?php fetchdir($ipages); ?>product.php?Name=<?php echo $name; ?>&id=<?php echo $id; ?>" ...
```

Comment: Also: the `&` needs to be url-encoded as `&amp;`.

Comment: It doesn't *need* to be. It depends on the HTML doctype.

Comment: It works un-encoded as well, but it needs to be encoded to be valid html.

Comment: I took out the `&` and replace it with @Maerlyn html code and i `syntax error, unexpected ';'`

Comment: The `&amp;` is HTML, not PHP.

Answer (score 3):

```
product.php?Name=$name&pid=$pid
```

You can use & to add two or more GET parameters to a URL.